# I have a variable, one of many in a structure and I would like to read information into it

Tags: c++, struct, user-input

I was able to get a clean compile until I decided to input information using this technique.  Once I get past this hurdle I will be able to try various scenarios and test the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main (void)
   {
    float test;                     /* a simple variable */

    struct seTup_backS_Format       /* the structure has about 30 variables */
       {
        float grnd_Elev;
        int many;     
       };

    string line;                    /* a string */

    getline(cin,line);
    stringstream (line) >> test;    // no problem

                                    // when I try

    stringsteam (line) >> seTup_backS_Format.grnd_Elev;    

               // the compiler says, expected primary-expression before '.' token ----

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a structure type, but not a structure variable. You should change your code as follows:

```
struct seTup_backS_Format       /* the structure has about 30 variables */
   {
    float grnd_Elev;
    int many;     
   } setup; // Declare a variable "setup" of type "struct seTup_backS_Format"

string line;                    /* a string */

getline(cin,line);
stringstream (line) >> test;    // no problem

                                // when I try

stringsteam (line) >> setup.grnd_Elev;
```